# Bundle exec rake db:migrate incompatible error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: linked to incompatible yU��.V - /home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date_core.so
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/messages/metadata.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/all.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/anubha/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/anubha/staging/wel-admin/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/anubha/staging/wel-admin/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/anubha/staging/wel-admin/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/anubha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

- Ruby version 3.2.2
- Rails version 6.1.6

when I run command "bundle exec rake db:migrate" Then the above error comes:

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is a mismatch between the Ruby version, gem date version, and the Rails version you are using.

Try to update your gems by running 'bundle install'.

If this doesn't work, check to see if the gems you are using are compatible with rails version you are using.